# simple score system in unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class score : MonoBehaviour {

     public int ballValue;
     public Text scoretext;
     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         ballValue = 0;

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         scoretext.text = ballValue.ToString();

     }

     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         if(other.gameObject.tag == "bucket")
         {
             ballValue = ballValue + 1;
         }
     }

 }
```

ok guys what am i doing wrong over here ,i am a beginner.what i am trying to achieve here is i want my ball to fall down to the bucket and get 1 point or score ,my ball has a actual circle collider and a rigidbody and my bucket has box collider which is a trigger and both of these are prefabs which is being used multiple times in the games just in case if anyone want to know.so can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong hereor can someone guide me to the right tutorial .thank you

(after playing with it for a whilei am able to get 1 point it does not increase and i am getting this error)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
and it refers to this line.

```
void Update () {
         scoretext.text = ballValue.ToString();

     }
```

ok guys i just found the real problem,as i said the bucket is a prefab which randomly generating like the pipes in flappy bird, so after creating my core system i drag and drop the text ui into the given place ,and i apply the changes and delete that prefab and when i go back to asset and check that prefab the given place for text says none.so how can i link the text ui directly to the script so it wont dlete it self.

Comment: is `OnTriggerEnter2D` called when the objects touch? does you bucket actually have the tag "bucket"?

Comment: ya it does contain the tags for both

Comment: There's something else should be going on. The code you posted should work (post more code and/or details?). Two things though if I may. 1-Why do you set the scoretext in Update(), instead of setting it only when the value actually changes? (OnTriggerEnter2D). 2-Depending on long term goals, might be wiser to have a collider only at the bottom of the bucket so players only score if the ball actually fell inside the bucket (this way, players score if the bucket was hit with the ball, even on the outside)

Comment: Thank you for advice mark,i have updated the question now there is an instance error cant figure out why and the score is not increasing it stay at 1 once the ball fall in and when the 2nd ball fall in nothing happens ,

Comment: That error means that `scoretext` is null aka not pointing to something.

Comment: Your problem with this: You said you have multiple buckets in your game, but each bucket has it's own script and score value. You need this value to be at a single spot and update it there.

Comment: A prefab is not part of the game itself (= it is not in the scene/hierarchy). That means that a public variable like you have can not point to something in the scene. Only if it is in the scene ifself. On runtime you need to get that reference in code, e.g. in `Start`. `FindWithTag("SomeTag").GetComponent<TheScript>()` is a good option to get an object.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get around this, is having a static class that holds the score and then have your buckets invoke a method in the static class to increase the score.

All you have to do then, is have an empty game object with the static class attached.